React App not able to fetch the response from API Gateway
Trying my first React Application.
I am getting the error when calling the API Gateway endpoint:
Endpoint works when I use Postman , Browser and Python Script
Error fetching session ID: Error: Failed to fetch
function App() {
  const [faceLivenessAnalysis, setFaceLivenessAnalysis] = React.useState(null)
  const [sessionId,setSessionId] = React.useState(null)
  const [loading,setLoading] = React.useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCreateLiveness = async () => {
        try {
             const response = await fetch('https://xxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev', {
              mode: 'no-cors'
          });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            const mockresponse= { sessionId:data.sessionId}
            setSessionId(mockresponse);
            setLoading(false);
            console.log('session:', data.sessionId);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching session ID:', error);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    fetchCreateLiveness();
  }, []);


what is the error from network tab of this request ?

try removing this:
mode: 'no-cors'
and see if it works.

if it still doesn't work, you're going to have to whitelist yourself on the server side.... if you don't have access to said server, then possibly headless browser api fetch with mock headers?...but you'll need to seed your own DB going that path and then provide your react app with that data.

@RJA Thanks removing no-cors worked I am able to get the session ID Now .. still getting an additional error but .. thanks for the tip

The problem seems to be the second argument with your fetch, {mode: "no-cors"}.
Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) often causes problems when you are running a React App in your local development environment.
I got a "DNS probe impossible" error with the example domain https://xxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev, so I instead use PotterDB, an API that doesn't require any keys in the example below.
See this:
import React from "react"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [faceLivenessAnalysis, setFaceLivenessAnalysis] = React.useState(null)
  const [sessionId,setSessionId] = React.useState(null)
  const [loading,setLoading] = React.useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCreateLiveness = async () => {
        try {
             const response = await fetch('https://wizard-world-api.herokuapp.com/Spells', {
              mode: 'cors'
              // contrast mode: 'no-cors'
          });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data)
            // const mockresponse= { sessionId:data.sessionId}
            // setSessionId(mockresponse);
            // setLoading(false);
            // console.log('session:', data.sessionId);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching session ID:', error);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    fetchCreateLiveness();
  }, [])}

When I use {mode: "no-cors"}, I get
"Error fetching session ID: Error: Failed to fetch at fetchCreateLiveness (App1.jsx:17:1)", i.e. the error you are seeing.
